# How to show the infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{(1+4^n)/(1+5^n)}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to show the infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{(1+4^n)/(1+5^n)}$ is convergent?

I found no duplicate question here similar to it so I've posted it here. I'm just learning basic series in real analysis & there it is a problem which I've to. Please help to find it out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One has
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+4^n}{1+5^n}} \sim \sqrt{\frac{4^n}{5^n}} = \left( \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\right)^n$$

This is the general term of a convergent series (as the general term of a geometric sequence that tends to $0$), so the first series also converges.

Comment: sir cant get it, please elaborate.

Comment: sir why are you sayoing that this is the general form?

Comment: Do you know what the symbol $\sim$ means ? If no, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: sir I couldn't find anything from your link, there is only a test named LCT(which I know), but what are you saying here dont get it.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, are you want to say sqrt(1+4^n/1+5^n) <= (sort {4/5})^n

Comment: No, I am saying that these two sequences are equivalent (in the sense that their quotient tends to $1$). Because they are positive sequences, the LCT tells you that both series converge, or both series diverge. But you know that the second series converges (it is a geometric series), so the first one too.

Answer (score -1):

We no every term in the sequence is positive, so the Partial Sums of the series are increasing. The sequence of partial sums increases monotonically.

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+4^n}}{\sqrt{1+5^n}}<\frac{\sqrt{1+4^n}}{\sqrt{5^n}}<\frac{\sqrt{4^{n+1}}}{\sqrt{5^n}}=2\cdot \frac{4^{n/2}}{5^{n/2}}$$

Now the term on the right forms a geometric sequence. The associated series has a finite limit. Can you find what it is?

The new series converges and its partial sums are always greater than the partial sums of the original series. Since the original series is monotonically increasing and can't exceed the limit of the new series it is bounded.

A monotonically increasing sequence bounded above converges.